# PHP - @ on top of everypage

Tags: php, debugging

I have an issue with my website. On every single page, there is an `@` on top of each page that I didn’t write.

It seems to come from my config file. Indeed, I begin each page with `require_once('config.php')`, if I do echo 'test' before the `require_once`, I get :

```
test @
```

But if I `echo 'test'` after the require_once, I get:

```
@ test
```

I use [`Sublime Text`](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (heard it could be an encoding error, tried to resave with `Notepad++`, nothing changed)

Have no idea what it can be.

Comment: SOMEWHERE you'ev got a file that php is executing that has the `@` outside of the `<?php ... ?>` code blocks. You'll need to figure out where. We can't help you, since we have no idea of what your code is doing.

Comment: Could you post your config file?(without passwords etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted about—and have dealt with—character encoding issues on many occasions. And the behavior you describe of you knowing the `@` is coming from the `config.php` file by testing the `echo 'test';` in `require_once` is not an encoding issue.

If this were an encoding issue, it would be garbage text/characters that would be at the top of the page or bottom of the page but could not be moved from those locations in the way you describe.

Somewhere in your `config.php` file there simply is an `@` floating in there that is either:

- The `@` is outside the context of the PHP opening & closing tags (`<?php`/`?>`).
- Something in your code is deliberately `echo`ing a `@`.
- Or—and this will be tricky—but depending on the complexity of your `config.php` file, it could be coming from another file that is being loaded via `require_once` or `include` within that `config.php` file.

The simplest thing to do right now is just open up the `config.php` file & do a search for the `@` character. Look at each instance of that showing up & the context of the line it’s in. If you are lucky, you will spot something that seems odd.

Past that the best debugging tactic right now is to do the same `echo 'test';` you did elsewhere solely in the `config.php` file itself.

- First place that at the top of the `config.php` file & load the page.
- Then place it at the bottom of the `config.php` file & load the page.
- Then you might have to go from line-to-line to see if you can pin point it.
- If you have to go from line-to-line, then split the difference. Go to the middle of the `config.php` and place the `echo 'test';` there. Then based on what you see, keep on placing that either above or below the middle of the page.

Yes, this can be tedious. But it’s the best way to handle a case like this.

Comment: I have already searched for @ and tried by commenting all included files. It doesn't come from there.. The weird thing is that my code works fine on my collegue's computer. We think it could be a local server issue. Thanks !

Comment: Edit : Actually you were right, the @ was at the end of one of the file required in the config.php I don't know why but even when the required line was commented, I still had the @. Thx anyway !

Comment: Thks for the information. We are both on windows. We used source tree (git) for versionning. He switched on my branch so maybe there also was an issue there.. It definitly was a line ending issue anyway. You are certainly right as it was after the closing bracket ?>